# Java - How to update file path in properties file for Windiows

Tags: java, log4j

I am trying to update log file path into a properties file. However, it is not updating properly and it is not creating the log file as well.

Code:

```
private void updateLog4jProperties(String operationName) {
    FileInputStream in;
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream("config/log4j.properties");
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.load(in);
        in.close();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("config/log4j.properties");
        if (System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().indexOf("windows") >= 0) {
            props.setProperty("log", "C:/temp/logs/myapp");
            Files.createDirectories(Paths.get("C:/temp/logs/myapp"));
        } else {
            props.setProperty("log", "/var/tmp/logs/myapp");
            Files.createDirectories(Paths.get("/var/tmp/logs/myapp"));
        }
        props.setProperty("log4j.appender.FILE.File", props.getProperty("log") + "/" + "myapp_"
                + operationName + "_" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(new Date()) + ".log");
        props.store(out, null);
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Resulting log4j.properties after execution:

```
#Thu Mar 02 17:24:46 IST 2023
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, FILE
log4j.appender.FILE.File=C\:/temp/logs/myapp/myapp_Test_20230302172446.log
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%d{HH\:mm\:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
log=C\:/temp/logs/myapp
```

If you see, value for both `'log'` and `'log4j.appender.FILE.File'` contains `'C\:'`.
Though it is creating the folder structure `'C:\temp\logs\myapp'`, log file `'myapp_Test_20230302172446.log'` is not present inside this folder.

Can you please help to identify the issue here.

Comment: There is nothing wrong here.  Your data has not been altered.  The `:` character is a special character in properties files, so the java.util.Properties class escaped it.  Read [the entire file format specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.Reader)) for details.

Comment: Once I hardcode path in log4j.properties to 'C:\temp\logs\myapp', it creates log file successfully. Issue is there only if I try to update this property from java code.